# Heat flow in 1D bar: why are the eigenfunctions used in the Fourier series orthogonal?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

> The temperature $T$ in a one-dimensional bar whose sides are perfectly insulated obeys the heat flow equation
>   $$
> \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}
> $$
>   where $\kappa$ is a positive constant. The bar extends from $x=0$ to $x=L$ and is perfectly insulated at $x=L$. At $t < 0$ the temperature is $0^\circ$C throughout  the bar and at $t=0$ the uninsulated end is placed in contact with a heat bath at $100^\circ$C. Show that the temperature of the bar at subsequent times is given by
>
> $$
> \frac{T}{100}=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4}{(2n+1) \pi} \sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L}\right) \exp \left[ - \kappa  \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L}\right)^2 t\right]
> $$

Here is what I have so far, and where I am stuck.

Assume separable solution $T(x,t) = F(t)G(x)$
$$
\frac{F'}{F} = \frac{\kappa G''}{G} = -\lambda
$$
So:
$$
F(t)\propto e^{- \lambda t}
$$
$$
G(x)\propto e^{\pm \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\kappa}} t}
$$
Let's define $q \equiv \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\kappa}}$ for convenience, giving a general solution of
$$
T(x,t)=T_0 + \sum_{q>0}e^{-\kappa q^2 t} \left[ A_q \sin q x + B_q \cos q x \right]
$$
We have 4 boundary conditions to apply:

1. $T(x,t) \to T_0$ as $T \to \infty$.
   This fixes the value of $T_0$ as $100^\circ$C.
2. $T(0,t)=T_0$ for all $t>0$.
   This sets all $B_q = 0$.
3. $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \Big|_{x=L}=0$.
   This sets $\cos (qL) = 0$, restricting $q$ to the values $q_n = \frac{\pi}{L}(\frac{1}{2} + n)$

So our solution now looks like

$$T(x,t) = T_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n e^{-kq_n^2 t} \sin{(q_n x)}$$

4. $T(0<x<L , t=0) = 0^\circ C$. Applying this to our solution gives:
   $$-T_0= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \sin{(q_n x)}$$

And here's the problem: I can't get out an expression for $A_n$. I would expect to take the inner product of each side with some $\sin mx$ to knock out some terms, giving me an expression for $A_n$.

The problem is that $\sin q_n x = \sin \frac{\pi}{L}(\frac{1}{2} + n)$ which is no longer orthogonal to $\sin mx$ over [0,L].

Perhaps I am meant to take the inner product with $\sin q_m x$. I've used Wolfram alpha to find out that $\sin q_n x$ and $\sin q_m x$ are indeed orthogonal for $n \neq m$ over $[0,L]$, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps I am meant to take the inner product with $\sin q_m x$.

Yes, that's the thing: you should take inner product of both sides with the eigenfunction whose coefficient you want to find. And here is why the eigenfunctions are orthogonal:

You are considering the eigenfunctions of $d^2/dx^2$ with boundary conditions $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi'(L)=0$. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two eigenfunction for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then 
$$
\lambda\int_0^L \phi(x)\psi(x)\,dx =  \int_0^L \phi''(x)\psi(x)\,dx 
= (\phi'\psi) |_0^L -\int_0^L \phi'(x)\psi'(x)\,dx 
\tag{1} $$
and 
$$
\mu\int_0^L \phi(x)\psi(x)\,dx =  \int_0^L \phi(x)\psi''(x)\,dx 
= (\phi\psi') |_0^L -\int_0^L \phi'(x)\psi'(x)\,dx 
\tag{2}$$
The boundary conditions ensure that in both (1) and (2), the boundary term is zero. Hence 
$$
\lambda\int_0^L \phi(x)\psi(x)\,dx = \mu\int_0^L \phi(x)\psi(x)\,dx
$$
which implies $ \int_0^L \phi(x)\psi(x)\,dx=0$.

---

More generally, the above argument works whenever the boundary conditions are such that 
$$(\phi'\psi)|_0^L = (\phi\psi')|_0^L \tag{3}$$
holds for all pairs $\phi,\psi$ satisfying these conditions. Such boundary conditions are called *symmetric*, and they are useful precisely because the corresponding eigenfunctions are orthogonal. The Dirichlet, Neumann, and Robin boundary conditions are all symmetric, and so is any mix of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understand it now!