# 1D diffusion equation with Robin boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, orthogonality, trigonometric-series

Solving $u_t = \alpha^2 u_{xx}$

with boundary and initial conditions

$u(0,t)=0$,

$u_x(1,t)+h u(1,t)=0$,

$u(x,0)=x$.

(Following the book by Farlow, "PDEs for scientists and engineers", page 54)

Before applying the initial condition the solution is

$u(x,t) = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n exp(-(\lambda_n \alpha)^2 t) \sin(\lambda_n x)$

where $\lambda_n$ are solutions to $tan(\lambda) = -\lambda/h.$

To find $A_n$ we multiply above by $\sin(\lambda_m x)$ and integrate $x$ between 0 and 1.

Now, in the book right hand side becomes:

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \int_0^1 \sin(\lambda_n x) \sin(\lambda_m x) dx = A_m \int_0^1 \sin^2(\lambda_m x) dx$

My question is: Why? And how can I prove it? I'm familiar with the concept of orthogonality of trig functions, but I didn't know the same rules follow for real coefficients of of $x$ ($\lambda_n$ and $\lambda_m$ rather than integers $m$ and $n$). Any hints or pointers towards the general theory will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenfunctions are orthogonal whenever the boundary conditions are *symmetric*, meaning that 
$$(\phi'\psi)|_0^1 = (\phi\psi')|_0^1   \tag{1}$$
holds for all pairs $\phi,\psi$ satisfying these conditions. This follows from double integration by parts [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099435). To verify that (1) holds in your case, observe that the terms at $x=0$ are zero, and the condition at $x=1$ turns (1) into  the identity
$$-h\phi(1)\psi(1) = -h\phi(1)\psi(1)$$

Comment: Why would sin be orthogonal in 0 to 1 if their frequencies are not integer multiples of $\pi$? and $\lambda_n$ do not seem to be integer multiples of pi.

Comment: Because of what I wrote.

Comment: I numerically calculated $\lambda_n$ for $h=3$  #### 4.078149764847837#
   7.472192659609594#
  10.722771062654415#
  13.924969952546746#
  17.105139536401282 #### And I am amazed that they are indeed orthogonal in 0 to 1. I did not expect this. Thanks.